# Code re factoring to a helper classes to avoid repetition but at the same time without compromising security

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

As among many, I have a .NET solution with many projects underneath.

The problem is this:

I use some lines of code repetitively in my project. Its kind of copy-pasting and I really hate that..

My idea is to move all these code in to a separate helper class but the following questions are preventing this idea:

The security aspect --> When I move this code out of my project, this means that somebody can still access it. If it were in my project, I could provide it security by making the concerned function "private".

So, the question is how to ***avoid code repetition*** but at the same time ***doing it securely* ?**

Some code to explain my concern:

> project A (of Solution S)

```
private Foo SomeSecureCode(IMyInterface interfaceObject)
{
     //Same some lines of code
}
```

> project B (of Solution S)

```
private Foo SomeSecureCode(IMyInterface interfaceObject)
{
    //Same some lines of code as above
}
```

Instead, moving this Function in a helper class but how making it securely?

(Minor details: I am using .NET version 4 with VS 2010)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what kind of code it is that you want to put in the helper. I don't know without knowing the specific code, but to me it feels that this might be solved by encapsulating it a bit better in proper objects.

Comment: @DirkBoer: I have some of my business logic code in it.

Comment: You seem to have a weird notion of security. In most applications `private` has no influence on security at all. It only matters in mixed trust applications where you sandbox some untrusted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a solution:

- Moven the class from project A to an other project (B) and make the class **internal**
- Sign the projects that want't t use the class with sn.exe and sign the project in the properties of the project.
- In project B add this to AssemblyInfo under the Properties folder of project B.

  [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Full.Assembly.Name.Here, PublicKey="Cut and past the public key of project A here>")]

Now you can use it only in project A and B.

To sign the project:

- Run [sn.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx)
- Call the result of Sn.exe sn.key
- Add sn.key to your project
- Open the properties of the project you wnt to sign (Alt+Enter)
- Go to tab "Signing
- Check the checkbox "Sign  the assembly
- Choose the strong name key in the combobox
- Compile the project

Now the project is signed you can make internals visible in an other project by adding the InternalsVisibleTo attribute to the AssemblyInfo of the project with the internal class.

Comment: Thanks alex. 'Internal' seems ok. but, could you explain me more about 'signing a project' (second point of your answer. Feels a difficult understanding it. Please elaborate]

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.I added some extra ino. Hope, this helps you to start with signing.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this points in right direction:

[InternalsVisibleToAttribute: Specifies that types that are ordinarily visible only within the current assembly are visible to a specified assembly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use inheritance and have the "helper" class be the base of the classes that need it?

```
sealed class A : C { }
sealed class B : C { } 
abstract class C { 
    protected Foo SomeSecureCode(IMyInterface interfaceObject); 
}
```

You can also use object composition and internal classes.

In one assembly:

```
class A { 
private Helper _helper; 
  private Foo SomeSecureCode(IMyInterface interfaceObject) { 
    return _helper.SomeSecureCode(interfaceObject); 
  }
}
```

And in a different assembly:

```
internal class Helper { 
  public Foo SomeSecureCode(IMyInterface interfaceObject) { 
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Then use the Assembly [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute in the assembly containing `Helper` to allow assemblies that need to see `Helper` to access it.

Also, keep in mind that anyone using your assembly could access and call your private method(s) using the Reflection API, and tools like dotpeek will let them see your code with only a little bit of information lost.

Comment: thanks for enlightning about the tools and reflection API. But, could you tell me why is that you are going for inheritance rather than helper class? Any specific advantage? For me, helper classes are ok rather than inheritance!